# MySQL keys acting a little strange

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a bit of a strange problem with MySQL that I've never seen before.  Basically, I need to enter the same entry into a table x number of times.  The Primary Key is auto increment so there shouldn't be any duplicate value problems.  However, it takes the last few columns and seems to clump them all into one value and is using that as a key.  The error I'm getting back is:

```
    Duplicate entry '80-0--2011-06-16-0-1' for key 'idx_mt'
```

Mind you, there is no field called idx_mt.  The primary key field is called just ID.  And that 80-0--2011-06-16-0-1 is the last 8 columns or so (which you can see the names of in the cols variable) concatenated, which they obviously shouldn't be doing.  Also, the first time the loop runs through, the entry goes through, but the later ones conflict with it.  I confirmed that this is the problem by changing one of the last 8 columns to a value based on a loop, and that went through with no problems.  Any insight?

```
    Dim cols As String = ""
    Dim msi As System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo = New System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo()

    cols = "TEMPLATE_NAME," & _
           "DESCRIPTION," & _
           "FORMAT," & _
           "SENDER," & _
           "`REPLY-TO`," & _
           "SUBJECT," & _
           "BODYHTML," & _
           "BODYTEXT," & _
           "CAMPAIGN_ID," & _
           "SPLIT_GROUP_ID," & _
           "TEMPLATE_IDENTIFIER," & _
           "MESSAGE_SEND_DATE," & _
           "DAYS_TO_DELAY_SEND," & _
           "ACTIVE"

    Try
        Dim test As Integer = CInt(cmbEffort.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Please use numerical values from 1 - 6 for the effort #.")
        Return
    End Try

    If (cmbEffort.Text < 1 Or cmbEffort.Text > 6) Then
        MsgBox("Please use numerical values from 1 - 6 for the effort #.")
        Return
    End If

    Dim query As String = ""
    Dim _date As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value
    Dim dateSent As String = ""
    Dim html As String = ""
    Dim temp As message

    If (_date.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Thursday) Then
        MsgBox("Selected date must be a Thursday.")
        Return
    End If

    dateSent = formatDate(_date)

    Try
        fileStreamIn = New IO.FileStream(txtHTML.Text, IO.FileMode.Open)
        streamReader = New IO.StreamReader(fileStreamIn)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("HTML File not found.")
        Return
    End Try

    html = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
    html = html.Replace("'", "&apos")

    streamReader.Close()

    server.query("SELECT * FROM TEMPLATES_TO_COPY WHERE CAMPAIGN_ID = " & cmpgnID)
    server.read()

    temp = getMessage(cmpgnID.ToString())
    temp.bodyText = txtMessage.Text
    temp.HTML = html
    temp.sendDate = dateSent
    temp.description = txtDescription.Text & "_" & cmbEffort.Text
    temp.campaignID = cmpgnID
    temp.name = temp.name.Replace("MMM", msi.GetMonthName(_date.Month).Substring(0, 3).ToUpper())
    temp.name = temp.name.Replace("YY", _date.Year.ToString().Substring(2, 2))

    For i As Integer = 1 To cmbEffort.Text
        temp.name = temp.name.Replace("X", (i + 1).ToString())
        query = "INSERT INTO MESSAGE_TEMPLATES (" & _
                cols & ")" & _
                "VALUES ('" & temp.name & "','" & temp.description & "','" & temp.format & "','" & temp.sender & "','" & temp.replyTo & "','" & temp.subject & "','" & temp.HTML & "','" & temp.bodyText & "'," & temp.campaignID & "," & 0 & ",'','" & temp.sendDate & "'," & temp.daysToDelay & "," & temp.active & ");"

        If (Not server.query(query)) Then
            Return
        End If
        temp.name = temp.name.Replace((i + 1).ToString(), "X")
    Next
```

Comment: Have you made a UNIQUE index on those 8 columns?

Comment: If you're referring to the table design, I wouldn't know.  The table was given to me by my supervisor.  How can I check?  We're using Navicat to view the databases.

Comment: I don't know Navicat, but I guess you can dump the structure of the table. Or just execute  `describe <yourtablename>`

Comment: I didn't get anything referring to a UNIQUE index on there, however, the column campaign_ID is labeled MUL under key (Yes, I mean Mul, not Null) and thats the column where the concatenating begins.  Could that be related?

Comment: Could be - yes, describe table doesn't tell all. I forgot. Use:  `show create table <yourtablename>`

Comment: What does `show create table` print?

Comment: The name of the table and a field called "Create Table"

Comment: Good you found the problem. The field "Create Table" should contain a complete CREATE TABLE definition with indexes and stuff.

Comment: I actually found what the problem was before hand (see post below).  There's an index being created with several fields.  The data I was using to test these fields was not unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is precisely what it says it is:

```
 Duplicate entry '80-0--2011-06-16-0-1' for key 'idx_mt'
```

There is a key/index that you have defined called `idx_mt`.  This key is set up among a handful of columns.  As others have pointed out in the comments, the values of all of those columns together are identical to a row already in your table, thus causing this conflict.

The duplicate entry with the fields concatenated together is how MySQL displays the value (and maybe even stores, I'm not sure) for that key.  It keeps track of it essentially like another column.  The values that are put there are made up of other columns in the table.

When you see `80-0--2011-06-16-0-1`, it means that the fields in this index on this particular row have the values of 80, 0, `null`, 2011-06-16, 0, and 1.  What you INSERT is conflicting with that.

Comment: Hmm...so basically, the table is configured to have a handful of columns set as a key?  Is this somehow different from a composite key?  Because the ID field is the only field marked as a key.

Comment: Ahh, I just stumbled upon a index tab in Navicat's Design View.  The index present is composed of those fields and is set to be unique.  Considering I'm not authorized to make these kind of changes to the database, I'm going to have to do a temporary work around until my supervisor comes up with something..Thanks!